# Reading multiple excel files as one data frame/table

Tags: r, excel, list, dataframe

I want to combine excel files together using R, and facing few issues:
1- I create a list of the files, so far only .xlsx as i want less problems for now.  `A <- list.files(pattern = '.xlsx', recursive = TRUE)`

2- `B <- lapply(A, read.xlsx)` I get an error: (Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  :
arguments imply differing number of rows: 92, 96, 76, 88).

3- Another problem has to do with columns type.

```
Error: Can't combine `..1$Ct.(dR)` <double> and `..7$Ct.(dR)` <character>.
```

I know usually how to use as.character, but since I have a list not an actual file, I am clueless.

*My plan is as follows:
-make list -> read them as excel files -> combine them into one file/table/df/matrix -> then visualize data

*My problems:

- column type different
- inconsistent raw, column numbers between files

Any help is appreicated.
I know that this has been asked before but unfortunately I was unable to replicate what was mentioned in the other questions&answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import multiple .csv files at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433432/how-to-import-multiple-csv-files-at-once)

Comment: you need to use this `list.files(pattern='*.xlsx')` with `*` mask?

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot this, you can print out the name of the file inside of the `lapply`:

```r
B <- lapply(A, function(x) {
   print(paste0("reading file: ", x))
   read.xlsx(x)
})
```

Once you you know which file causes the problem, you can provide more details
and possibly a [repex](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/).